# How to make Flutter Responsive app for all platform

Tags: flutter

Which is best dependency or method to make flutter responsive to all platforms.

I tried using Screenutil and Media Query but don't exactly know how to do it

Comment: Please make sure that your questions are as precise as possible. Your question appears to be very broad and hard to solved.

You should definitely checkout the official flutter page on how to do that:
https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout/adaptive-responsive .

I once wrote a test project which is responsive for mobile & web. Maybe that also helps you: https://github.com/raLaaaa/gorala-client .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Ferox use below Class to make your UI responsive

```
class Responsive extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget mobile;
  final Widget tablet;
  final Widget desktop;

const Responsive({
 Key? key,
required this.mobile,
required this.tablet,
required this.desktop,
}) : super(key: key);


static bool isMobile(BuildContext context) =>
  MediaQuery.of(context).size.width < 850;

static bool isTablet(BuildContext context) =>
  MediaQuery.of(context).size.width < 1100 &&
  MediaQuery.of(context).size.width >= 850;

static bool isDesktop(BuildContext context) =>
  MediaQuery.of(context).size.width >= 1100;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

if (size.width >= 1100) {
  return desktop;
} else if (size.width >= 850) {
  return tablet;
} else {
  return mobile;
}
}
}
```

and use it like

```
   if (Responsive.isDesktop(context))
            Container(),//your UI
```